# XeLatex equations and content placement between lines

Tags: math-mode, xetex, margins, templates, alignment

How I make sure in the following template to place the equations and the statments to be exactly between the lines. They never come over any lines always in between the lines and on the right of the red margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for dummy text, remove in your actual document
\usepackage{setspace}

% Page geometry
\geometry{
  left=30mm, % Adjusted to accommodate the red line
  top=25mm,
  right=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  headheight=0pt, % Adjust as necessary
  headsep=0pt, % Adjust as necessary
  footskip=12mm, % Adjust as necessary
}

% Define colors
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{173,216,230}
\definecolor{lightred}{RGB}{255,204,203}

% Line spacing to match the TikZ lines, adjust the multiplier as needed
\setstretch{1.255} % Adjust this value as needed

% Header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Background setup
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPicture{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south west)}]
            % Draw vertical line
            \draw [line width=1mm, lightred] (25mm,0) -- (25mm,297mm); % A4 paper is 210mm wide and 297mm high
            
            % Draw horizontal lines
            \foreach \i in {1,...,30} {
                \draw [lightblue] (0,\i*9mm) -- (\paperwidth,\i*9mm);
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% Ensure the background picture is drawn on every page
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\BackgroundPicture}

\begin{document}

this is to check the placement of the words.

\begin{equation*}
    E=mc^2
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    a &= b\\
    c &= d
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The output is in the following image for the current template.

Comment: How did you determine the space betweeen the blue lines (currently 9mm, right)? Are you allowed to change this setting?

Comment: I am open for any change but the content and mathematical equations should come in between lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easy to align the text, but hard for other stuff. You need manually adjust the space in between. Here is an example. I put the red line on the left margin. And the text will be aligned if there is no other type of contents (e.g., eqns,figures,tables). As you can see, if you want add these contents, you need manually adjust them, in order to make the following text aligned.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for dummy text, remove in your actual document
\usepackage{setspace}

% Page geometry
\geometry{
  left=30mm, % Adjusted to accommodate the red line
  top=25mm,
  right=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  headheight=0pt, % Adjust as necessary
  headsep=0pt, % Adjust as necessary
  footskip=12mm, % Adjust as necessary
  showframe
}

% Define colors
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{173,216,230}
\definecolor{lightred}{RGB}{255,204,203}

% Line spacing to match the TikZ lines, adjust the multiplier as needed
\setstretch{1.255} % Adjust this value as needed

% Header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Background setup
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPicture{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.north west)}]
            % Draw vertical line
            \draw [line width=1mm, lightred] (1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin-0.5\pgflinewidth,0) -- (1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin-0.5\pgflinewidth,-\paperheight); % A4 paper is 210mm wide and 297mm high
            
            % Draw horizontal lines
            \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\inteval{\textheight/\baselineskip-1}} {
                \draw [lightblue] (0,\dimexpr-25mm-\fpeval{\i*\baselineskip}pt-\topskip) -- (\paperwidth,\dimexpr-25mm-\fpeval{\i*\baselineskip}pt-\topskip);
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% Ensure the background picture is drawn on every page
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\BackgroundPicture}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{equation*}
    E=mc^2
\end{equation*}\vspace{\dimexpr-0.5em-\baselineskip}
\begin{align*}
    a &= b\\[-2pt]
    c &= d
\end{align*}\vspace{\dimexpr2.5pt-\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1]\vspace{2pt}

{\centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\par}\vspace{3.5pt}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]